# Get Directory Listing Content using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a website which I desire to browse the `https://somewebsite/public/images/` folder, which is possible through the browser. I want to map the contents of it and do a bunch of stuff. But I am having a hard time getting the contents of said folder using nodejs. Is there a way to get the contents of a remote directory? 
I have no access to the code of this website whatsoever. To give you more information about this. I don't have access anymore to this website, the credentials to access it were lost, and I have to retrieve all the files from it.

Answer (score 1):

You really should provide more information, like if you're using `express` and what you've tried so far.

If you are using Express, the easiest thing to do would be to install the [serve-index](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-index.html) module and configure it.

```
$ npm install --save serve-index
```

Then in your express startup file:

```
var express    = require('express')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')

var app = express()

// Serve URLs like /ftp/thing as public/ftp/thing
app.use('/images', serveIndex('public/images', {'icons': true}))
app.listen()
```